# Disabling separator for a specific UITableView section

Tags: ios, uitableview, separator

I'm designing a Login page and I'm using a table with 3 section.

First section: 1 cell containing header image
Second section: 2 cells for username and password
Third section: 1 cell for login button.

[image: 3 section design]

I would like to disable the separator for only for the 1st and 3rd section cells and leaving it active for the 2nd section. At the moment I can only enable/disable the separator for all the cells.

Any solution?

Thanks a lot

Claus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a dirty way to do this, but you could disable the separators (as I don't think you can control them on a cell-level, but I could be wrong here), and draw the line manually?

You could, like, use a stretchable UIImage and put a gray pixel png into it, then stretch it to fill the cell width. This would allow you to even pick the color of the separator :-)
Or just insert an UIView and set its backgroundcolor. Whatever you like.

Edit: On a side note, I'm not sure why you're using an UITableView anyway. You're not taking advantage of any feature of UITableView here (like scrolling, lazy loading, anything at all).

Comment: I've tried to place a static UITableView inside a UIView but Xcode keeps on saying "Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances"

Comment: What I mean is, why do you use UITableViews at all. From what I see, you just need a few UI objects dragged into a plain UIView? However, that was just a side remark from me, you can of course use the table view if you wish so.

Comment: You're simply right..I just found out how I can add an UIView as footer and header of the TableView. At the first sign it looked not possible.
thanks